# Do stack exchange sites prohibit cross posting on other sites outside stack exchange?

Tags: support

Do stack exchange sites prohibit cross posting  outside stack exchange?

Is it  allowed to not indicate  identical posting on stack exchange?   ( One benefit is to receive independent responses, and the other is for account  privacy.)
Some sites encourage sharing posts of stack exchange sites with  them, although I am not concerned about "sharing", but identical independent posts, and the order of posting might   matter (where posting happens first: SE  or  other sites).

Is it appropriate that a user on stack exchange accuses another user of doing so?

It is not specific to U&L. I don't ask on meta.stackexchange.com, because they have been too "friendly" to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit of a question of opinion. Some users feel very strongly that asking the same question in two places, even if the second is not part of the SE network, should not be allowed. As I understand it, their position is that you are asking people to duplicate the work since you ask in different locations.

Speaking for myself, I don't see how we (SE users) could possibly insist on this. We do not own the internet and if you want to ask on another site, then you have every right to do so. Speaking as a moderator, we can only impose rules about *this* network of sites. So yes, there is a rule against cross-posting the same question on multiple SE sites, but there is no rule that says you cannot post on Reddit, for example, if you have posted here.

Now, although there is no such rule since we do not own the internet, it is considered polite to also include a link to your other question. So, if you ask on Reddit and then ask the same question here, it would be nice to include a link to your Reddit post so that the two questions can be linked and information shared between them. It would be even nicer if you repost any useful answers from Reddit as answers to your question here (with proper attribution, of course). However, these are "nice to have" things, not strict rules.

Answer (score 3):

No, all content on Stack Exchange is licensed as [CC BY SA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing), version [3.0 or 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344491/295232), and that means you're free to

> **Share** — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>
> **Adapt** — remix, transform, and build upon the material
>   for any purpose, even commercially.

([source](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/))

This obviously includes posting questions outside the Stack Exchange network. However, you **must** provide proper attribution while doing so ([unless you wrote the question yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89377/295232)):

> **Attribution** — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

---

> Is it appropriate that a user on stack exchange accuses another user of doing so?

It depends how you define 'accusation', but it could very well be against the [Code of Conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct) and thus worth flagging.

Comment: I think Tim is asking about posting his own question elsewhere, not somebody else's. Also, nice to see you around these parts! :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the clarification - it wasn't really clear from the initial version.